# Solutions to Polynomials of different degrees

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions, algebraic-curves

We have $p(x)$ a degree $m$ polynomial and $q(x)$ a degree $k$ polynomial. We also know that $p(x) = q(x)$ has at least $n+1$ solutions. And, $n\geq m\land n\geq k$.

Now, I tried graphing a little to see if I see a pattern

I tried making $$y= x^{2} $$ 
and 
$$y = -x^{2}+5 $$
There were two points of intersection so $n$ was $1$ in some sense here while the degrees were $2$.

Then the only way I thought that the condition can hold for $n+1$ solutions and $n \geq m $ and $ n \geq k$ is if $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are the same polynomial.

That was the answer to this problem. But can someone give an idea for this please.

Comment: Seems unclear what the question was, about polynomials.

Answer (score 3):

$P(x) - Q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $\max(m,k)$, and therefore has at most $\max(m,k)$ roots unless it is the $0$ polynomial, i.e. unless $P = Q$.

Comment: Oh wow yeah that makes sense. Thank you sir. And since we are saying $$ n \geq max(m,k) $$ we must have $$P(x) = Q(x)$$ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**just a hint**

If the equation $R (x)=P (x)-Q (x)=0$ has at least $n+1$ solutions, it means that degree of $R (x)\ge n+1$.

but degree of $R (x)\le \max(m,k) $
thus
$m\ge n+1$

or  $k\ge n+1$